# How to detect duplicate value in a list of URLs and stop iteration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape a website using `puppeteer` & `cron`. It's working fine except I can't figure out how to stop the program execution if duplicate url is detected?

Here's the pseudo code of my project:

```
// target = grab the <a> tag from site

// page.goto(target)

// grab all data

// save it to the file
```

While this code is running fine, when I run this script on scheduler/`cron`, I want to somehow detect if the `<a>` tag from the source site is already scraped, and just stop the code from scraping the old link again and saving duplicate data into the field every time the `cron` function runs.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Based on this limited information, I would suggest to use a Map kind of datastructure to keep track if a url is scrapped or not. Map has constant lookup time and can be very quick to check.

Comment: Create a global list and add each link to list after it was scrapped. Use if/else to check if link is already in list for all following links

Comment: I tried doing this. but the script is running in scheduler. so the next time it runs, the global list that I'm tracking gets reset to 0 so I lose all the stored urls that were scraped. so next time the scheduler run, I have nothing to compare this new value against. that's the main issue here. should I add scraped url to some database and retrieve & match value against every run and check it was scraped? it seems like lot of work for accomplishing a simple task. @JaSON

Comment: Try to save your list in simple text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are grabbing some list of URLs and then just iterate over it. So it should be like this:

//variable keeping your list of URLs
//variable (array/map) with a list of already checked URLs

//iteration over URLs

//check if URL is in the list of already checked ones if it is then continue to the next iteration

//target = grab the  tag from site

//page.goto(target)

// grab all data

// save it to  the file
// save URL in your variable that contains a list of already checked

Comment: I'm grabbing a list of urls. but once I get them. I'm only interested in the first url and scrape it. it's a news website I'm scraping. so in my scheduler I want to run function for every hour and check if the url I grabbed got updated (like there's new story) then I want to scrape it, but if it's old story i.e. same url as previous run, I don't want to scrape until next scheduler run. I tried doing `forEach` but it doesn't Work coz every time it runs the array I'm tracking gets reset to 0 and I don't have any frame of reference/value to compare the new value against the old one.

Comment: So you can keep information about it in some database / file or whatever else you want so you will have possibility to check if site should be scrapped.